# How can I make the name of a website to appear in bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies

I am new at Latex, so Im sorry if I made things too complicated.
I want to cite a website and @article probably isn't the best option for this, but here is what I tried:

```
 @article{struers,
  title={About Grinding and Polishing},
  author={Struers - Ensuring Certainty},
  isbn={},
  url={https://www.struers.com/en/Knowledge/Grinding-and-polishing#},
  year={2020}}
```

There wasn't a specific author mentioned in the website, but I want the name of the website to appear in references instead. Therefore I tried to put it as it was the author, but then it appears as this in the bibliography page:

```
[2]  S. E. Certainty.  About grinding and polishing.  2020
```

while using:

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
```

So the question is, how can I make the websites name appear fully in references without messing up my other citations? Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should consider using `biblatex`, which defines an `@online` entry type.

Comment: Hey thank you :) Though I think this doesnt solve the problem with shortened author names :(

Comment: You're dealing with a so-called "corporate" author. Hence, change `author={Struers - Ensuring Certainty},` to `author={{Struers - Ensuring Certainty}},`.

Comment: Off-topic: (i) It's *wrong* to use the `@article` entry type for the entry in question, as it's not a piece that was published in a scholarly journal. I suggest you use `@misc` instead. (ii) The `abbrv` bibliography style doesn't know about, and hence simply ignores, fields of type `url`. I suggest you either switch to the `abbrvnat` bib style and load the `natbib` citation management package with the option `numbers`, or change the field to `note={url\{https://www.struers.com/en/Knowledge/Grinding-and-polishing#}},` and load the `url` or, better yet, `xurl` package.

Comment: @Tuana: With the `@online` entry type, the `author` field is not mandatory, I should have mentioned it. You can look at p. 11 of the documentation.

Comment: thank you so much for both of your answers! :)